# What does assembly include when using internal as access modifier?

Tags: c#, encapsulation

> Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same
>   assembly,

I'm afraid that I don't know exactly what does assembly mean in C#.

Could you please explain it's definition when defining member as internal?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=.NET+assembly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each project (`.csproj` file) in a solution (`.sln` file) will produce an assembly. (each .exe file or .dll file is considered an assembly)

When a member is `internal` it is seen as `public` to all other classes in the same project but it is seen as `private` to all classes outside of the project.

Comment: What are the cases I need to use public member in other program?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed when you want other projects to be able to call your code. For example you are making a DLL for other people to use, all the functions that people can call will need to be public.

Answer (score 3):

An assembly equals the .DLL or .EXE produced by all the compilation units (files) included in the project that creates said assembly.

So when a class or class member is marked `internal` then that means it is accessible only by code that is included in that assembly.

Comment: Assemblies can also be dynamically created without persisting to a DLL or executable, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394699/net-dynamic-assemblies.